# Twitter messages on website with votes

Tags: twitter

I am not sure how it is done, therefore my questions below:

I would like to ask folks on Twitter for a suggestion on a particular topic. Can I tell them to use certain hashtag and have all comments with that hashtag posted on my site?

Do I just pick a hashtag or does it need to be created somehow?

Can I have users on my site rate those suggestions? In that case, would I need to somehow grab twitter message and store locally?

Just trying to understand the process in order to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Hashtags don't have to be created - just use it in tweet.

In order to get all tweets with particular hashtag, use search API: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search and search for this hashtag. You should save all relevant tweets (twitter search is not reliable on old tweets).

Comment: Cool. I guess I could write some script that will add a message ID and then some script run via crone job to check if particular ID is saved and if not, save it. And on a separate page I can output messages from my db... something like this. Thanks.